# How to read an excel file uploaded and convert to json in angular

Tags: angular

Can some one help on How to read an excel file uploaded and convert to json in angular.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file` use this npm package.

Install

`npm install read-excel-file --save`

In html

`<input type="file" id="input" />`

ts

```
import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file'

const input = document.getElementById('input')

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then((rows) => {
    // `rows` is an array of rows
    // each row being an array of cells.
  })
})
```

[Demo](https://catamphetamine.github.io/read-excel-file/)